Añadir icono para gestionar wifi en bspwn
Me instalé el entorno de bspwm de s4v1tar pero no tiene para gestionar la Wi-Fi desde la polybar. Alguien sabe si es posible añadirlo? Hay otros métodos para gestionar Wi-Fi pero es cuestión de comodidad....muchas gracias de antemano
